# How can I pass an enum into a constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, enums, arguments

I want to do something like this:

```
public class MyEnumTest {

    public enum MyEnum;
    private MyEnum value;

    public MyEnumTest(enum e)
    {
        this.MyEnum = e; 
        this.value = this.MyEnum.values[0]//Set value to the first enum value.
    }

    public void setValue(MyEnum e)
    {
        this.value = e; 
    }

    public MyEnum getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

}
```

and call it something like this:

```
MyEnumTest car = new MyEnumTest({HONDA, FORD, TOYOTA, HOLDEN}); 
MyEnumTest fruit = new MyEnumTest({APPLE, BANANA, CHERRY}); 

/* some operations occur*/ 

if (car.getValue() == car.FORD) System.out.println("Vrooom!"); 
if (fruit.getValue()) == fruit.APPLE) System.out.println ("Is red and round and delicious");
```

Any ideas for doing this?

For bonus marks - would it be possible to set the initial value using the enum values? 
eg something like

```
MyEnumTest myET = new myEnumTest(new enum {RED, GREEN, BLUE, YELLOW}, BLUE);
```

Comment: Your question is confusing - do you want to specifically use your `MyEnum`, or any enum?

Comment: I want to be able to create instances of a class, and create them with any Enum I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others said it's hard to understand what you are trying to do, but here is my best guess:

```
public enum Color {
    RED, GREEN, YELLOW, BLUE;
}


public class MyEnumTest<E extends Enum<E>> {
    private final Class<E> enumType;
    private final E value; 

    public Class<E> getEnumType() {
        return enumType;
    }

    public E getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public MyEnumTest(Class<E> enumType, E value) {
        this.enumType = enumType;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MyEnumTest(Class<E> enumType) {
        this(enumType, enumType.getEnumConstants()[0]);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        // no initial value provided
        MyEnumTest<Color> myET = new MyEnumTest<Color>(Color.class);
        if (myET.getValue() == Color.RED) {
            System.out.println("It's probably an apple");
        }

        // providing an initial value
        myET = new MyEnumTest<Color>(Color.class, Color.YELLOW);
        if (myET.getValue() == Color.YELLOW) {
            System.out.println("It's probably a banana");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, keep in mind that enum values are static... So, something like myET.MyEnum.RED doesn't make sense... You should use instead: Color.RED

Comment: +1 Nice work, this takes what I sketched out and does a good job of molding it toward the seeming intent of the OP.

Answer (score 6):

You could use (without the `enum` keyword):

```
public MyEnumTest(MyEnum e)
{
    this.myEnum = e; 
    this.value = MyEnum.values()[0];
}
```

For part 2, you could define an overloaded constructor:

```
public MyEnumTest(MyEnum[] myEnums) {
```

and to use:

```
MyEnumTest myET = new MyEnumTest(new MyEnum[] { MyEnum.FOO, ... });
```

Comment: Note that `values()` is a static method.

Comment: +1 And you could make it take `MyEnum...` (varargs) to make the array creation implicit.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do. Reimeus's answer shows what to do with your specific `MyEnum` as an argument. If you want to implement your class to use any enum, use the following:

```
public class MyEnumTest<E extends Enum<E>> {

    private final E firstValue;

    public MyEnumTest(Class<E> enumType)
    {
        this.firstValue = enumType.getEnumConstants()[0];
    }

    ...
}
```

And instantiate it like this:

```
MyEnumTest myET = new myEnumTest(MyEnum.class);
```